# Hibernate Criteria setReadOnly doesn't work on second query

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, criteria, hibernate-session

```
    @RequestMapping("/testing") 
    @Transactional
    public String testing(HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model) 
    {               

        Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Student.class);      
        criteria.setReadOnly(true);

        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", "ID12345"));

        List<Student> result =  criteria.list();                

        Student abc = result.get(0);

        abc.setFirstname("AAA");                

        Criteria criteria2 = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Student.class);             
        criteria2.setReadOnly(false);


        criteria2.add(Restrictions.eq("id", "ID12345"));

        result =  criteria2.list();             

        Student abc2 = result.get(0);

        abc2.setFirstname("BBB");

        return "testing";
    }
```

As the code above, it has `setReadOnly` to true for `criteria`, so `firstName` will not be `AAA` (in database), but it has reset the `setReadOnly` to false for `criteria2`, why the `firstname` didn't become `BBB` (in database)?

Comment: do you not need to save the entity?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I already simplify the scenario, in my actual code, it has few layer of service and model class and few method in between. So I created this simplified scenario to find out the root cause of my issue. Yes, I want to save the entity, but I wouldn't be able to remove `criteria.setReadOnly(true)` (it is in other method).

Comment: What if you place the second call in a method marked @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) to start new transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some time of research, I managed to find out the reason.

While the first query load up the object, hibernate put the object in persistent context and mark the object as `read-only`. Meaning the object will not be flushed in the end.

During second call to load up the object, hibernate fetch the object in persistent context instead of making call to database again, because the fetch is based on primary key. Since it is loaded from persistent context, it will be still in `read-only` state.

In order to let the object back to flush-able again, we can use `setReadOnly(Object entity, boolean readOnly)` to set back the `readOnly` of the object.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Early in the transaction my entity was loaded as `read-only=true`, later trying to re-load the entity with `read-only=false` - I saw that the Hibernate entity state was still `READONLY`. By running `if session.isReadOnly(entity) { session.setReadOnly(entity, true); }` it reset the entity state to `MANAGED` and allowed my update to persist. `NOTE:` I had to set `read-only=false` BEFORE I made the change to the entity, or it wouldn't be persisted.